# SSH hangs on remote command execution after prompting for password

Tags: linux, redhat

I am able to execute remote commands as the root user, but not unprivileged user "admin":

```
[user@jump01 ~]$ ssh admin@10.50.11.1 'ls'
admin@10.50.1.1's password: 
^CKilled by signal 2.
[user@jump01 ~]$
```

I can, however, log in with SSH interactively without any problems and run any command I want.

Comment: It's probably a hangup in your shell startup files, caused by the noninteractive login.  If your shell is bash, try running e.g. `ssh admin@10.50.11.1 'set -o xtrace && ls'`.  The output will show you the last command that runs before it hangs.